# Using a nodejs server to load files with Unicode names

Tags: node.js, unicode, filenames

I want to load audio files with names like `здраво.mp3`, using a NodeJS server. (That's "zdravo" or "hello" in Serbian, if you were wondering).

However, NodeJS makes a request for `%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE.mp3` instead, which results in the file not being found.

If I drag the file into a browser window from my desktop, the browser is happy to load it as file///path/здраво.mp3, so the issue is not with the way the browser is treating the Unicode string

The HTML page containing the link to the file has this meta tag in the head section...

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

... and it is quite happy to display the text "Здраво" on the page, so the Unicode strings are properly formed within the browser.

I am guessing that the browser is converting the name to ISO-8859-1 before sending the request, and that the NodeJS server somehow needs to convert it back to Unicode before looking for it in the file system.

My question is: is there already a module that I can use to do this conversion, and are there examples of how to use it?

SOLUTION: Following the reply from Edwin Dalorzo, here is the one-line fix that I made to my handleRequest() function:

```
function handleRequest(request, response) {

  request.url = decodeURIComponent(request.url) // the fix
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname
```

Comment: Well you could simply do `decodeURIComponent(url)` and you would get back `здраво`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how you are receiving the encoded string, but for sure you can decode by simply doing:

```
decodeURIComponent("%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE")
```

And this will give you back your string `"здраво"`